# tkinter report frame as well as mouse coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
 def mouse_click(event):
    #'reports' to both terminal and results text box
    parent_name = Frame.winfo_parent(root)
    parent = Frame._nametowidget(parent_name)
    result = ("{0}: {1},{2}\n ".format('Clicked at', event.x, event.y))
    print('clicked at',parent,  event.x, event.y)

from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Change Text")
root.geometry('700x500')

top=root.winfo_toplevel()
for rn in range(0,9): # rn = row number
    top.rowconfigure(rn, weight=1)
top.rowconfigure(rn, weight=0)    
for cn in range(0,5): # cn = column number
    top.columnconfigure(cn, weight=1)
# FRAME 1
frame1 = Frame(root,  borderwidth = 2, background = '#EFE0CD', relief = RIDGE,width = 25, height = 20)
frame1.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_click)
frame1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 3, sticky = N+S+E+W)
frame1_lbl = Label(frame1, text='Frame 1', font='comic-sans-MS 10 ', fg ='red', bg = '#EFE0CD')
frame1_lbl.grid(row=0, column =0)

# FRAME 2
frame2 = Frame(root,  borderwidth = 2, background = '#CCC6B0', relief = RIDGE,width = 25, height = 20)
frame2.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_click)
frame2.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 3, sticky = N+S+E+W)
frame2_lbl = Label(frame2, text='Frame 2', font='comic-sans-MS 10', fg ='red', bg = '#CCC6B0')
frame2_lbl.grid(row=0, column =0,)
root.mainloop()
```

I know that this is a really dumb question. How do I identify the Frame in which the mouse is clicked so that report prints clicked frame1 or frame2 at x y coordinates?. I found a bit about using winfo_parent but have obviously not used it properly.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event object that is passed in to the callback has a `widget` attribute which is a reference to the widget that got the event. So, `event.widget` is what you want to print.

Comment: Do I somehow use ._nametowidget to get the Frame's name? Thank you for your help. event.widget gives me a number. Not quite sure how to convert this to a name. Using ._nametowidget() tells me that it lacks the argument name. Sorry for being ignorant!

Comment: print('clicked at',event.widget._nametowidget(root), event.x, event.y) Using this gives me dot x y?

Comment: I have now tried w = event.widget print(w.winfo_name()) which still gives a number and not the name. Does drop the . before the digit though

Comment: What do you expect to get for the name? The variable name? You can't get that, nor do you need it. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: 'Need' to report which frame was clicked and where - just refinements to my GUI. I have also posed another question relating to a text box that I hoped would wrap and scroll but resizes instead. Would you mind looking at that one as well...?tkinter textbox resizes instead of wrapping text to fill box was the 'title'

Comment: Why are you reporting it? What purpose does that serve? Are you just doing that to help you debug? You can always give the frames a name attribute, and query that if you really need a human-readable name.

Comment: Thank for your help. Just an exercise, nothing more. Appreciate your time and help though